# Making a Quiz In visual basic that requires a highscore feature which isnt working correctly

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a quiz and it requires a highscore function as said before. When I run the program everything is fine except that the highest score won't always be the highest score.

If I retake it, a lower score will still replace the highest. scores aren't showing in the 2nd and 3rd highest brackets either which I assume is with the same problem..

Here's the code--  (With each question answered correctly there is score += 1, then calling score update at the end of last question. )

```
Public score As Integer = 0
'best score
Dim highest As Integer
'second best
Dim scoreuno As Integer
'third best
Dim scoredos As Integer


Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub scoreupdate()
    highScore.Text = highest.ToString
    score2.Text = scoreuno.ToString
    score3.Text = scoredos.ToString
End Sub

Public Sub highscores()
    If score > highest Then
        scoredos = scoreuno
        scoreuno = highest
        highest = score
    ElseIf score > scoreuno Then
        scoredos = scoreuno
        scoreuno = score
    ElseIf score > scoredos Then
        scoredos = score
    End If
    scoreupdate()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    score = 0
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I presume that `highScore`, `score2` and `score3` are Labels or Textboxes - are they positioned in the right order? Unless I'm missing something, the code you supplied should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code a little by using a list of integers like this

```
Dim HighScores As New List(Of Integer)
```

Then, instead of using your current `HighScores` sub using the sub below, just add a score to the list which is sorted in to highest value first, and then the lowest value is removed from the end of the list.

This way, if you decide to have more than 3 high scores, it should work just fine. just change the maxHighscores variable instead of having to edit your `If` statement and add increasing amounts of code. Then just add code into your update sub to show the additional scores.

```
Private Sub AddScoreIfHighEnough(score As Integer, maxScoresCount As Integer)
    'Adds score to list
    HighScores.Add(score)
    'Sorts list into ascending order and reverses the order
    HighScores.Sort()
    HighScores.Reverse()
    'if the number of scores is greater than the maximum allowed
    'number remove the extra scores
    While maxScoresCount < HighScores.Count
        HighScores.RemoveAt(HighScores.Count - 1)
    End While
End Sub
```

To use it just add replace each time you use

```
highScores()
```

with

```
AddScoreIfHighEnough(score,3)
```

Finally to assign your scores, just use

```
Private Sub scoreupdate()
    highScore.Text = HighScores(0).ToString
    score2.Text = HighScores(1).ToString
    score3.Text = HighScores(2).ToString
End Sub
```